# Vulnerabilities appears npm install npm audit npm audit fix --force in windows 10 , npm 6.4.1 node v10.13.0

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

npm audit

```
                   === npm audit security report ===


                             Manual Review
         Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve

      Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance
```

Moderate        Prototype Pollution

Package         hoek

Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3

Dependency of   otp.js [dev]

Path            otp.js > joi > hoek

More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/566

Low             Denial of Service

Package         mem

Patched in      >=4.0.0

Dependency of   react-native

Path            react-native > @react-native-community/cli > metro >
                  metro-inspector-proxy > yargs > os-locale > mem

More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/1084

> > .......
> >     npm audit fix --force
> >     Error:
> >     npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.

npm WARN commonmark-react-renderer@4.3.4 requires a peer of commonmark@^0.27.0 || ^0.26.0 || ^0.24.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@17.1.1 requires a peer of eslint@^4.19.1 || ^5.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb-base@13.2.0 requires a peer of eslint@^4.19.1 || ^5.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.7.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN jsdom@15.2.1 requires a peer of canvas@^2.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN ws@7.2.3 requires a peer of bufferutil@^4.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ws@7.2.3 requires a peer of utf-8-validate@^5.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN react-native-fast-image@7.0.2 requires a peer of react-native@^0.60.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN react-native-keyboard-input@5.4.1 requires a peer of react-native@^0.57.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-responsive-ui@1.1.1 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN react-native-responsive-ui@1.1.1 requires a peer of react-native@^0.43.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN react-navigation-drawer@1.4.0 requires a peer of react-native-screens@^1.0.0 || ^1.0.0-alpha but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN react-navigation-stack@1.10.3 requires a peer of react-native-screens@^1.0.0 || ^1.0.0-alpha but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself

> > >
> >     >
> >     up to date in 20.457s
> >     fixed 0 of 6 vulnerabilities in 1710074 scanned packages
> >       6 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated

anyone could help plz????

Answer (score 0):

problem was with 'npm install' and 'npm yarn install'
This helped me

'choco install yarn'
'cd project_folder'
'yarn global add react-native-cli'
'yarn'